# Assign variable the grep value of command output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have been recently introduced to the world of bash scripting. I currently have a video of file which I want to grep the duration. The problem is assigning the duration value to a variable. I get the errors shown below. What is the best way to assign duration value to a variable? Also is it necessary to have two greps. For example the first grep gives `duration=171.805000`, Then i have to do a second grep for the decimal value only.

snippet

```
#!/bin/bash/
str_duration=echo$(ffprobe -i "media/myvideo.mp4" -show_format -v quiet | grep duration)
int_duration=echo ${str_duration} | grep -o ' [0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

error

```
line 15: echoduration=171.805000: command not found
```

command output

```
ffprobe version git-2014-12-27-d4fd3f2 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 27 2014 12:23:47 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavformat    56. 16.102 / 56. 16.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/media/myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.16.102
  Duration: 00:02:51.81, start: 0.000333, bitrate: 1504 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1367 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
duration=171.805000
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ffprobe -i "media/myvideo.mp4" -show_format -v quiet`

Comment: @Sobrique output posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...  To answer your question about the error, you need a space after the `echo` command.

But wait, there's more.

You probably don't really want the word "echo" as part of your duration variable.  You'd use echo to *display output* of some kind, not to gather data and store it in a variable.  Variable assignments are in the form of `variable=value` or `read variable` which can take a value from a variety of sources.

Note that without the `-v quiet`, the ffprobe command will dump a plethora of data to `stderr`, so it's important to include it to reduce the noise of your script.

The output of your (quieted) `ffprobe` command would include something like this:

```
duration=171.805000
```

You can do a number of things with this format of data (my goodness, it looks like `variable=value`...), but the easiest might be to use `cut`.

```
file="media/myvideo.mp4"
str_duration=$(ffprobe -i "$file" -show_format -v quiet | grep ^duration | cut -d= -f2)
```

Note that this approach of using the equals as a field separator might fail for *other* fields which might include their own equals sign.  But it should be safe for duration.

Alternately, you could use tools like `awk` or `sed` to reduce the number of pipes:

```
str_duration=$(ffprobe -i "$file" -show_format -v quiet | sed -ne '/^duration=/s///p')
```

or

```
str_duration=$(ffprobe -i "$file" -show_format -v quiet | awk -F= '$1=="duration"{print $2}')
```

I am purposely *not* going to tell you how to use the `eval` command to take ffprobe's output and assign it directly as a variable within your script, because the `eval` command is *very* dangerous if you don't check and limit its input.  As a beginning shell programmer, you should read about `eval` and then not use it until you feel that you're somewhere between "intermediate" and "advanced". :)

Alternately, you can use Input Field Separators to parse this data in bash:

```
declare -A details
while IFS== read field value; do
  details[$field]="$value"
done < <(ffprobe -i "$file" -show_format -v quiet | grep '.=.')

echo "${details[duration]}"
```

This takes the output of the ffprobe command and commits it to the elements of an array, which you can read as per the `echo` line.  It is safe for content that includes an equals sign, because of the limited number of variables mentioned in the `read` command.

Note that except in the case of this last example, ALL the commands in this answer are compatible with traditional /bin/sh, not just bash.

Comment: After some consideration this is the best answer. However I am getting this error `line 18: syntax error near unexpected token do'  IFS== while read field value; do'` and ther is a missing `{` for `echo "${details[duration]"`

Comment: Ah, a think-o on my part.  The `IFS` assignment needs to be applied to the `read` command, not the `while`.  I've corrected the error in my answer, please try again with the corrected command line. And thanks!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
str_duration=$(ffprobe -i "media/myvideo.mp4" -show_format -v quiet | grep duration | awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
```

You dont need echo. Also the output generated by your command is:

```
duration=171.805000
```

And you need to assign numbers to str_duration variable and hence with awk you get numbers whatever is after "=".

Comment: If you're adding `awk` to the pipeline anyway, why leave `grep` in there?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
duration=$( ffprobe -i "media/myvideo.mp4" -show_format -v quiet | grep duration | sed 's/.*=//g' )
```

If you wanted 'just' the number:

```
duration=$( ffprobe -i "media/myvideo.mp4" -show_format -v quiet | grep ^duration | sed -e 's/.*=//' -e 's/\..*//' )
```

Comment: If you're recommending `sed`, why bother with `grep`? (`... | sed -n '/duration/s.*=//gp'`)